# MVC5 jQuery client side validation not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an MVC view model which I would like to validate in the client.  I have read lots of posts on here about the order of the libraries, but I have mirrored those suggestions and still am unable to get the validation working.  On form submit I reach the `Customer/CreateCustomer` controller method without any validation.  The web.config parameters appear to be set correctly (both relevant values set to true) in the root and the Views folder.

I am using MVC5 with Visual Studio 2013.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class CreateCustomerVm
{
    [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCustomer", "Customer"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create"/>
}
```

Rendered section:

```
<form action="/Customer/CreateCustomer" method="post">    
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="rSLp5Rwtq9rqwwrAs8UN_CsgPbXEVG_enkISIhWrkXOokprATgbRcpPNk7o6F6EaxD-9I92f7kAr7TGTFPZe0pUSZ5Rfrz8CoP3ef8-lqhXUhSVAaX7PkmmURR1XcaXQ0" />
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Name">Customer Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Customer Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="BBC-TV" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

In my _layout page i have this at the bottom:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Finally my BundleConfig:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.form.js"
                    ));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"
                    ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

Comment: What is `jquery.form.js`? What errors do you get in the browser console?

Comment: put this https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js  in  ~/bundles/jquery , should resolve

Comment: check your browser's console for errors. You seem to be missing the base jQuery library and the unobtrusive validation library. If you really did follow some tutorials on this then either they were wrong or you missed part of the process. See here https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Client-Side-validations-using-Data-Annotation-attributes-and-jQuery.aspx and here https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Bundles-ScriptBundle-in-ASPNet-MVC-Razor.aspx for the basics

Comment: Move '@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")' to top of _layout page, inside head section.

Comment: Thanks @Hadee that appears to be the solution!  I was sure i tried that...